# Terraform lambda with dependencies (required includes) without using layers

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I am new to terraform but I am following some documentation for an app I am trying to support and I am having a little trouble understanding how this works.

Example TF for Lambdas:

```
data "archive_file" "handler_lambda_archive_file" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../lambda/js/submit-handler"
  output_path = "${path.module}/submit-handler.zip"
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "handler_lambda_function" {
  function_name = "app-${var.app_lifecycle}-submit-handler-lambda"

  filename         = data.archive_file.handler_lambda_archive_file.output_path
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.handler_lambda_archive_file.output_path)

  handler = "main.handler"
  runtime = "nodejs14.x"
  timeout = 240

  role = aws_iam_role.handler_lambda_iam_role.arn

  environment {
    variables = {
      app_lifecycle                     = var.app_lifecycle
    }
  }

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = var.subnets_for_lambda
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.handler_lambda_sg.id]
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "handler_lambda_function2" {
    function_name = "zoom-${var.app_lifecycle}-submit-handler2-lambda"
  
    filename         = data.archive_file.handler_lambda_archive_file.output_path
    source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.handler_lambda_archive_file.output_path)
  
    handler = "main.handler"
    runtime = "nodejs14.x"
    timeout = 240
  
    role = aws_iam_role.handler_lambda_iam_role.arn
  
    environment {
      variables = {
        app_lifecycle                     = var.app_lifecycle
      }
    }
  
    vpc_config {
      subnet_ids         = var.subnets_for_lambda
      security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.handler_lambda_sg.id]
    }
  
    tags = var.tags
  }
```

In the `source_dir` folder, there are the following files:

`main.js`, `auth.js`, `shared.js`.

In both the main and auth JS files, there is a line at the top requiring the include:
`const someSharedFunction = require("./shared.js");`

If I understand, there will be two lambda functions created with the following names:

`app-sandbox-submit-handler-lambda` and `app-sandbox-submit-handler2-lambda`

My question is regarding that `shared.js` file. The archive file contains all 3 js files in the zip and will create the terraform functions using that.

Does it detect that there is a `require` in those files and automatically put a copy of the `shared.js` file into each one of the functions so that it can be used?

It isn't using layers, so I'm just not sure how the requires work in this case.

**Question:**

Does the terraform detect require when creating the functions and include any referenced files with the lambda?

Comment: I believe this question pertains more to AWS Lambda functionalityexpectations than Terraform, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is looking at your JavaScript code and detecting that a `require` is pulling in some dependency. Terraform isn't looking at your Lambda function's code at all.

What is happening is the entire directory is being zipped, because you are giving a `source_dir` to the `archive_file` resource.

Comment: Hm, interesting. So the same source files that get zipped and then the lambdas are created by the individual `aws_lambda_function`s in TF can reference any of the files in that `source_dir`. Would they show up on both of the individual functions file tree structure when viewing the code source of an individual lambda function?

Comment: Yes, you are creating two Lambda functions from the same zip file, so the two functions literally have the exact same source code. You're even calling the same handler function on both functions, and setting the same environment variables. At this point there is no difference in these two Lambda functions at all.

Comment: Got it, thanks! My example was a bit off with the identical code, but it answers my question about how a file can be shared between the other functions if from the same source.